# How clustered indexing is implemented in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have googled, but still a little confused. How is clustered index implemented in SQL Server? Is it implemented using B+ tree?

Answer (score 0):

Searching can be hard. But, with this search "sql server clustered index data structure" on Google, the [first link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx) is the answer from MS. They claim as follows

By default, a clustered index has a single partition. When a clustered index has multiple partitions, each partition has a B-tree structure that contains the data for that specific partition. (answer applies to Sql 2005 & 2008)

Personally, I don't necessarily trust answers like this to be accurate just because MS says it is so (docs not matching the implementation being all too common) and I know that SQL server can create a hashed index, but given that a hashed index would not "cluster the data values", it would seem very unlikely that MS would ever use a hash index for a clustered index. Now, if MS adds bitmap index support in the future, it would seem feasible that this could apply to a clustered index.

Comment: Do you know what you're talking about? How possibly could you cluster data on disk with bitmap index.

Comment: Does not seem very likely to me, but I was thinking of using an in-memory bitmap index with data clustering. A clustered index may logically by constructed using a bitmap index, probably not in a traditional use case (low cardinality) -- so yeah, it would be feasible though the use case would be limited at best. There are a number of non-btree implenations that could theoretically be feasible, but btree works so well in the general cases they are unlikely to ever be used. There was an IEEE paper on using a bitmap index with data clustering a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

To give you general idea you have tree over records sorted on the disk, physically. This means records on hard drive maintain the order determined by the index. But over that you have regular "nonclustered" index that instead of pointing to leafs with values stored, point to records on hard drive.

This mechanism is pretty straightforward and widely used. For example PostgreSQL has functionality to cluster table based on non-clustered index which enforces the physical order of data on disk.

This is no s-f so I would be really surprised if there was relevant difference between documentation description of Clustered Index and implementation. Also this is so core concept that it would be a terrible idea.